# HOG +SVM training with iniria dataset, TypeError: samples is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: numpy, dataset, svm, glob, image-recognition

I'm working on *pedestrian detection* with a team. I am trying to figure out an error that keeps showing up that says "TypeError: samples is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" which when appear points to the line of code that is `svm.train(X_data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels12)`

i tried following **dozens** of online guides but i still couldn't solve the problem, and im also very new to this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import feature
from skimage import exposure
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# training

X_data = []
labels1 = []
label = []
files = glob.glob ("new_pos_1/crop*.PNG")
for myFile in files:
    # print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread(myFile,)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    X_data.append (image)
    labels1.append('Pedestrian')


print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
labels12 = np.array([labels1])
print('labels12 shape:',np.array(labels12).shape)
print('labels shape:', np.array(labels1).shape)
#Testing
Y_data = []

files = glob.glob ("new_pos_1/person*.PNG")
for myFile in files:
    # print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Y_data.append (image)
    label.append('Pedestrian')

print('Y_data shape:', np.array(Y_data).shape)

print('label shape:', np.array(label).shape)

hog_features = []
for image in np.array(X_data):
    (fd, hogImage) = feature.hog(image, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), cells_per_block=(2, 2),
                                    transform_sqrt=True, block_norm="L2-Hys", visualise=True)
    hogImage = exposure.rescale_intensity(hogImage, out_range=(0, 255))
    hogImage = hogImage.astype("uint8")
    hog_features.append(fd)

print("I'm done hogging")
print(hog_features)
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
svm.setC(2.67)
svm.setGamma(5.383)
print("Done initializing SVM parameters")
# Train SVM on training data
svm.train(X_data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels12)
print("Done trainning")
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
print("SAVED.")
#testResponse = svm.predict(testData)[1].ravel()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The line at the beginning that says `labels12 = np.array([labels1])` i used to try and fix the error that showed up to no avail.
This is the original website that helped me write this code: https://www.learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should also do `X_data2 = np.array([X_data])` and call `svm.train(X_data2, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels12)`